# Reactjs fetch data from Api?

Tags: reactjs

I am fetching images from the server. Why the console.log(images) inside the useEffect is a empty array, but outside the useEffect it return the data.

```
const ImageGrid = () => {
    const [images, setImages] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`https://api.unsplash.com/photos/?client_id=${key}&per_page=28`)
            .then(res => {
                return res.json();
            })
            .then(images => {
                setImages(images);
            });
        console.log(images);
    }, []);

    console.log(images);
    return (
        <div className="content">
            <section className="grid">
                {images.map(image => (
                    <div>
                        <img src={image.urls.small} alt={image.user.username} />
                    </div>
                ))}
            </section>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: the body of your `useEffect` doesn't execute in the order you are thinking it does. it's going to call fetch and then call your console.log immediately. You should move your `console.log(images)` into the last callback that gets called after the data has been returned

Comment: put your console.log inside the last "then" statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you need to know API calls are asynchronous. And return value of them is a promise.
So in your example inside `useEffect` you are calling API using `fetch` so basically it is asynchronous. and once API call is finished depending on returned promise state it calls `then` block or `catch` block.
If promise gets successfully resolved then it calls `then` block else if promise gets rejected then it goes into `catch` block.
Now your `console.log` inside `useEffect` is not logging the data because it will get executed immediately after the call to API and it does not wait for API response to get back.
And outside `console.log` is logging the data because after response is returned inside `then` block you are calling `setImages` so after calling this your function component get re-rendered this causes your second `console.log` to print data.

See this for references -

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API
- https://javascript.info/async-await